# Change text in label to "hi" after you click the button

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

What is wrong with this it is meant to change text in label to "hi" after you click the button.

ViewController.swift:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  HelloSwift
//
//  Created by Abdel Rahman Osman on 10/13/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Abdel Rahman Osman. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TextGoesHere: UILabel!
    @IBAction func PrintText(sender: AnyObject) {
        var Text = TextGoesHere.text
        Text = "Hi"
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Please help me fix this code as I am new to app development.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is creating a copy of the text in the label, discard it and reassign a new value, and then discard it again when the variable goes out of scope.

The correct way is by assigning the text directly to the `text` property:

```
@IBAction func PrintText(sender: AnyObject) {
    TextGoesHere.text = "Hi"
}
```

Comment: i was wondering how to change the text of the label, when the button was pressed. Sorry as my question might not have been clear.

Comment: Are you saying that the code in my answer doesn't change the text in the label?

Comment: Yes, it does not change the text in the label.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on that line and check that: the method is actually invoked; the `TextGoesHere` property is not nil

Comment: when I run the program it runs but takes me this line, class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: Does that happens after making the changes I proposed, or even with your version? If the answer is yes, then the problem is probably elsewhere and hard to track down

Comment: Even with my version.

Comment: Is it worth creating another product and trying the same thing?

Comment: If it's just a new project, maybe yes. Doesn't the error reported when the app breaks say anything useful?